# Split string using multiple patterns, where second pattern matches smaller parts of the first

Tags: java, regex

I'm reading special "formatting codes" in a string and am trying to split the string so that I have those formatting codes and the string's text separated.

There are two "types" of formatting codes: "Encoded" hex colors: `§x§7§3§7§5§f§f` and other codes in the format of `§r`.

Given the example string: `§x§7§3§7§5§f§f§ltest1 §rtest2`

I need the larger pattern split as a whole, and then the smaller ones. I can do what I want on those patterns separately, but am having trouble combining them into a single regex. Because the second pattern matches pieces of the first pattern, it's just splitting everything into smaller groups.

I'm trying this:

```
for (String substr : "§x§7§3§7§5§f§f§ltest1 §rtest2".split("((?<=(§x(§[0-9a-f]){6}))|(?<=§[0-9a-z])|(?=§[0-9a-z]))")) {
  System.out.println(substr);
}
```

My **expected** output is:

```
§x§7§3§7§5§f§f
§l
test1
§r
test
```

My **actual** output is:

```
§x
§7
§3
§7
§5
§f
§f
§l
test1
§r
test2
```

When I split the expressions up into different `split` tests, they work, they're just not working *together*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of splitting, you could just use this simplified regex for matching:

```
§x(?:§[0-9a-f]){6}|§[0-9a-z]|[^§\s]+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aCaKZZ/2)

**RegEx Details:**

- `§x(?:§[0-9a-f]){6}`: Match text starting with `§x` and 6 hex characters
- `|`: OR
- `§[0-9a-z]`: Match text starting with `§` and an alphanumeric
- `|`: OR
- `[^§\s]+`: Match 1+ non-whitespace and non-`§` characters

**Code:**

```
final String regex = "§x(?:§[0-9a-f]){6}|§[0-9a-z]|[^§\\s]+";
final String string = "§x§7§3§7§5§f§f§ltest1 §rtest2";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println( matcher.group(0) );
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly it seems. Is there any performance benefit to this over `split` as well? Perf isn't a huge concern here, it's not going to run very often, but is worth paying attention to.

Comment: This will be more efficient for. sure as there are no look arounds

Comment: I notice that if the `§r` is moved, it's no longer separated, though I'm not sure why because the regex is still matching it in the regex101 tests. `§x§7§3§7§5§f§f§ltest1§r test2`

Comment: Looks like `§x(?:§[0-9a-f]){6}|§[0-9a-z]|[^§]+` works, though needs to be tweaked to ignore whitespace too.

Comment: Yes that's indeed a good idea. I have just updated answer with `[^§\s]+` option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

[See it working here](https://regex101.com/r/7QYcdp/1)

```
 ?((?:§[^§])(?=[^§])|[^§ ]{2,})
```

How it works:

- `?` optionally match the space character
- `((?:§[^§])(?=[^§])|[^§ ]{2,})` capture either of the following:

  - `(?:§[^§])(?=[^§])` match the following:

    - `(?:§[^§])` match `§` followed by any character except `§`
    - `(?=[^§])` lookahead ensuring what follows is not `§` (same as `(?!§)` but more efficient)
  - `[^§ ]{2,}` match any character except `§` or space two or more times

With the substitution of `\n$1`

Result:

```
§x§7§3§7§5§f§f
§l
test1
§r
test2
```

Comment: Could this be adapted into `split` though? I'm not actually looking for new lines between each segment, I need to run logic on each component (primarily converting the format codes into something usable), so I need to be able to iterate them in the order the "output" implies.

Comment: @helion3 you should add that second string sample to your question and add the expected results.